# When I click the button, can the image place on skeleton joints? What should I write in coding?

Tags: c#, kinect

Can I know how to solve this problem? I was creating a kinect to placing image on skeleton joints.

http://i860.photobucket.com/albums/ab166/season04/Untitled_zps8781ac62.png

and the code are stated below:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (SkeletonData data in e.SkeletonFrame.Skeletons)
        {
            foreach (Joint joint in data.Joints)
            {
                if (joint.Position.W < 0.6f) return;
                switch (joint.ID)
                {
                    case JointID.Head:
                        var heanp = getDisplayPosition(joint);

                        Canvas.SetLeft(imgHead, heanp.X);
                        Canvas.SetTop(imgHead, heanp.Y);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If there's any mistake...please correct me...T_T

Comment: What's the problem? What's not working?

Comment: It shows that there's an error on "SkeletonFrame" about the System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs does not contain a definition for skeletonframe and no extension method 'skeletonframe' accepting a first argument of type 'system.windows.routedeventargs' could be found ( are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference )

I don't know how to solve this... I just want to place an image on skeletonjoints when i click a button by using kinect... T_T

Comment: I do not know myself so well with kinect but you get this error because `RoutedEventArgs` has no SkeletonFrame Property

Comment: @AhFoo - why do you think `RoutedEventArgs` has a `SkeletonFrame` property? Have you copied the code from somewhere?

Comment: the link above is a screenshot the errors i facing right now.. By the way, I also don't know weather this code works or not...=( 
If there's any mistakes, please correct me... T_T thanks a lot

Comment: I had a void SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e) on top. 
If i place the coding inside there, there's no errors shown but if i place in private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) it shows that error.

Comment: Thats because `SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs` **has** a Property `SkeletonFrame` but your Button click event has `RoutedEventArgs` which has no `SkeletonFrame` Property

Comment: I had a void SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e) on top there is used to determine which hand is used to be cursorhand.

Comment: @Mark OH THANKS!!! THANKS A LOT!!! but now i having one more new error. I try to solve it before i ask again. THANKS A LOT!

Comment: I have maked an answer from my comment

Comment: What is ' No overload for 'button1_Click' matches delegate 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler' ???

Comment: is it that i have to add a routedeventargs on the private void button1_Click???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because `SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs` has a Property `SkeletonFrame` but your Button click event has `RoutedEventArgs` which has no `SkeletonFrame` Property

Comment: Thanks!! There's another problem 
What is ' No overload for 'button1_Click' matches delegate 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler' ???
is it that i have to add a RoutedEventArgs on the private void button1_Click too??

Comment: did you changed your `private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` to `private void button1_Click(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)` ?

Comment: Yeah, I did. Is it because of no RoutedEventArgs so it pop out this error?

Comment: That is not working the delegate for the button click event 
is predefined every button click event you're doind has the same syntax 
`private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` and can't simply be changed.

Comment: So where should i put SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs? If I write 
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) the previous error is solve...>< how to mix them?

Comment: you can't mix them you should put them in a list or something like that when their ready and then access in your click event to that list. But that is a other question

Comment: don't change it make a new question about your problem that you want your SkeletonFrames avaible in your click event